# how do I use repeated action in past tenses

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between :

1- I played football for 5 years
2- I was playing football for 5 years

Comment: If you **were playing** football for five years... I really hope you won.

Comment: As usual with aspectual questions, the difference is not in the objective facts, but _entirely_ in the choice of the speaker/writer, whether to present the events as a continuing process or a finished action.

Comment: You could also consider "I used to play football" for repeated action, although it sounds odd with a time phrase.

Answer (score 0):

1. *I played football for 5 years*: You played the sport and then stopped.
2. *I was playing football for 5 years*: needs context. In particular you'd expect it to be followed by *when...* What happened after? Did you suffer an injury?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a tricky question, because it can really depend on what the context is. Grammatically, the difference is between the action being framed as complete or continuous, but the various past tenses in English are tricky and can have different implications depending on the situation.

> I played football for five years.

The most natural way of interpreting this is that, over those five years, you had a hobby or habit of playing football. You could also read it as playing football for five years continuously, which would be a very, very long game. At this scale, it's a silly idea, but grammatically it makes sense. Compare that to "I played football for five hours," where the opposite is the case: it makes more sense to interpret that you had a very long game/tournament of football. Either way, the playing is now complete; it's over and finished.

> I was playing football for five years.

This is more unnatural and sounds odd, but it's not grammatically *wrong*. I'm not sure exactly how to interpret it. Were you playing a five-year-long game of football? On its own, that's kinda how I'd have to parse it.

Generally, I'd say that the first construction is far common and probably what you'll want to use.